# Set manual limit in any axis of matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

Is it possible to set manual x or y axis limit in matplotlib such as:
I am having data in range of 0 to 4500 in x-axis.
But if there are more values in range of 0 to 500.
Can I set values on x-axis such as 0,100,200,300,400,500,1500,2500,3500,4500.
We can use:

```
plt.xlim(0,4500)
```

But above command will set all values with same difference in between all values from start to end.

```
0,100,200,300,400,500,1500,2500,3500,4500
```

Is there a way such that I can set values in x axis like mentioned above or something similar to it.
Any help would be great
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html). The same exists for [`yticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yticks.html).

Comment: xtick and ytick will be used to set low and higher limit but it won't let us set manually like I have given above in two range. Such as first few values with difference of 50 and after that values with difference of 1000

Comment: Do you want `plt.xticks([0,100,200,300,400,500,1500,2500,3500,4500])`? Or `plt.xticks(range(10), [0,100,200,300,400,500,1500,2500,3500,4500])`?   Or maybe the first solution together with `plt.xscale('log')`?  Everything strongly depends on what and how you want to plot.  Some curves? A scatter plot? Barplot? ....?

Comment: Is the problem that you want to stretch the x-axis so that it is "zoomed in" at the lower end and "zoomed out" at the higher end? Kind of like a log scale? It may be helpful for you to provide more information about your problem. Perhaps include a graph showing what you have and describing what you want.